# Marionette multiple controllers for nested views

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Im wondering how to structure nested controllers in Marionette, I have this hierarchy

```
Menu (module)
  MenuController
    MenuItemCollectionView
        MenuItemView
            MenuItemDropdownController
                MenuItemDropdownLayout
                    MenuItemDropdownSidebarView
                    MenuItemDropdownContentView
```

Basicly im building a navigation menu similar to polygon.com (when you hover over items a "dropdown" appear).

I looked alot after some examples of "nested controllers" in Marionette but without luck, my understanding is i need to separate out a Controller for each Dropdown, and maybe aslo a controller for each MenuItemView. The way ive seen examples of something similar is that the "High level controller" is responsible for everything. Maybe my understanding of controllers in Marionette is wrong, and they are more intented for Routing purpose.

How would you guys structure this would you have the MenuItemView be responsible for creating a MenuItemDropdownController? (which i find abit odd.)

Or maybe im thinking about this the wrong way maybe this should be separated into multiple modules? but i cant really wrap that around in my head, as i see modules as single items like a "Menu" / "Login form" etc and not items in a collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have one single controller to handle your menu.

This case should be manageable using composite views, and I wrote a blog post with a similar objective here: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/

The complexity of your various subviews could also be handled by using Marionette layouts.

You can see an example of a controller handling a layout here (see contactsListLayout): https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L43

Basically, a layout is "a view containing subviews in their own regions".

Handling nested layouts is explained in more detail in the book that builds the above app (available [here](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction/)).

Comment: These suggestions will get you quite far given the example above. I often find it difficult to decide whether to branch out to a different dedicated controller when you want to move from a general view of (composed) data into a specialized view. Take for example a dashboard view, comprising of lots of different data. I might use a DashboardController to orchestrate this but when I want to view an aspect in more detail I might switch to another controller altogether. Do you nest, branch or invert?

Comment: I tend to use one controller per "job to be done", which tends to be similar in concept to created RESTful resources: one resource per "thing".

Answer (score 0):

Neither backbone nor Marionette have strong opinion on how a controller should be used beyond routing.

In practice controllers and routes are used to put applications into a specific state, in your example I think you are overusing controllers. In your case a single controller should be enough to handle your menu.